# How to set path to prev directory Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I use this function to get current path to directory where is placed Python script:

```
def get_script_path(self):
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

I want to set up path to one directory upper from current catalog to catalog `/advs`:

I tried:

```
filename = 'file.txt'
filepath = os.path.join(self.get_script_path(), '../advs', filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below it will give the path of previous directory in which running script is present

```
import os
path_to_prev_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

filename = 'file.txt'
filepath = os.path.join(path_to_prev_dir, 'advs', filename)
```

Comment: But where concate `'/advs/file.txt'`?

Comment: concate can be done using same method that you did updating the answer

Comment: Like this: `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + /advs/file.txt`?

Comment: I have updated the answer ..you can use `os.path.join` to get the your expected path from prev dir

Comment: You don't want to pass `'/advs'` to `os.path.join`; it's already adding the separators, so just pass `'advs'`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - yup you are right ..updating the answer